# Grails and Hibernate - Lots of domain objects with lots of properties

Tags: hibernate, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've got a problem that I addressed in another question, but this is a larger question:

A default Grails project using STS has Spring/Hibernate under the covers. When a Grails application loads up, my database of 100,000+ domain objects appears to be loaded in memory. Whether or not this is at the Hiberate/ORM layer, I have no idea.

```
Pre DB domain object load (400 MB start up)
Post DB domain object load (900 MB start up)
```

This is without any boot strap data. No app performance out of the box. Just a clean start up and my domain objects.

I can use monitors, but I get the same answers. This appears to be configuration. How can I set up Hibernate within Grails to not load these objects into memory?

This is the datasource.groovy file:

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"
}
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = false
cache.use_query_cache = true
cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
    }
}
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
    }
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
    }
}
}
```

This is killing me because I have tried all types of tweaks to start up files (boot strap, datasource/hibernate, config, etc - I can't even recall every different thing I have tried).

*** Edit ***
I am not using eager fetching with my objects. Just default lazy.

Answer (score 3):

How are you getting your pre/post memory numbers?   It doesn't feel likely to me that your entire set of domain objects is getting loaded into memory unless you've got a very weird plugin or something extra in your BootStrap.groovy file.

Probably the easiest way to see if this is really happening is to just turn on trace level logging for hibernate:

```
trace 'org.hibernate.SQL'
```

If it's really loading all that in memory from the DB, you'll see a massive amount of SQL queries going on when the app starts.

To investigate more, I'd probably look at turning on [JMX Monitoring of hibernate](http://grails.org/MBean+export+the+Groovy+way), and then connecting `jconsole` to your running grails instance to dig into the details of what's loaded and what isn't.

Comment: great hint to use the SQL trace!

Comment: Excellent tip about the trace. I'll try that out.